# SSL Lets Encrypt после обновления два сертификата

Tags: nginx, ssl, letsencrypt

nginx

Установил вручную SSL Lets Encrypt. Проработал три месяца корректно. Истечь должен был 22го октября.

18го октября обновил вручную командами:

```
cd /opt/letsencrypt

./letsencrypt-auto renew
```

Вроде все обновилось. Сегодня при заходе на сайт браузеры начали кричать что подключение не защищено и сертификат не корректный.

Запустил проверку сервисом https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

Увидел следующее: будто установлено два сертификата.

**Certificate #1: RSA 2048 bits (SHA256withRSA)** корректный, с датой до января.

И второй сертификат:

**Certificate #2: RSA 2048 bits (SHA256withRSA)**

истекший.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я не могу понять, он показывает предыдущий истекший вместе  с новым? Или он должен был обновиться и отображаться только текущий сертификат? Почему браузеры начали выдавать ошибку SLL?

**Команда**

```
ls -l /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain/
```

выдает следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: посмотрите что у вас выводит  ls -l /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain/ (Бывает так что после обновления letsencrypt не кладет сертификаты с теми же именами и нужно поправлять)

Comment: @noname2019 добавил в вопрос эту информацию скриншотом. Взгляните пожалуйста

Comment: странно, по идее правильно указывает (если только номер 2 в конце названий сертификатов в папке архивов максимальный, я имею ввиду что нет номеров 3-4 и т.д и 2 это самый высокий)

Comment: а что дает этот номер? Просто сертификат обновлялся пока только один раз. Если я правильно думаю, цифра - это количество обновлений? Кстати сейчас сайт вроде открывается корректно. Может быть какой то кэш?..Возможно такое?

Comment: да номер так и есть, а насчет кеша вполне возможно. хотя я с таким не сталкивался

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обновить сертификаты не достаточно, нужно еще подгрузить новые сертификаты в веб-сервер.

**nginx:**

```
nginx reload
```

**apache (один из вариантов):**

```
service apache2 reload
service httpd reload
/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

и т.д.

Ну и конечно, `letsencrypt` создавался для автоматизации продления сертификатов, нужно добавить в `cron` скрипт для продления сертификатов.
Запускаем от `root` команду:

```
crontan -e
```

Добавляем скрипт на новой строке, который будет выполняться дважды в день.

```
0 */12 * * * /opt/letsencrypt/letsencrypt-auto renew
```

Далее нужно прописать перезагрузку конфигов после обновления сертификата, например для `nginx` создать файл **/etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/deploy/01-reload-nginx** и занести в него следующий код:

```
#! /bin/sh
set -e
/etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Только не совсем понял, как настроить автообновление. Что делать со строкой /etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/deploy/01-reload-nginx ?

Comment: @Amsterdam, обновил ответ. Эта строка - файл который нужно создать, при условии конечно что у вас существует директория `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal-hooks/deploy/`

Comment: Вот незадача..Перезагрузил сервер, и опять ошибка сертификата начала выскакивать в браузерах. Обновить заново не дает, пишет "No renewals were attempted.". Ничего не понимаю теперь окончательно...Что можно сделать ?

Comment: в конфиге `nginx` проверить пути до сертификатов, они должны быть примерно такими: `/etc/letsencrypt/live/my_domain/cert.pem` и т.д.

Comment: в конфиге - это в файле nginx.conf ? Если речь о нем, то там совсем нет никаких упоминаний SSL..

Comment: Можно как то удалить старый сертификат и просто поставить новый? Сайт в реальном времени теряет посетителей пока это происходит...

Comment: `grep letsencrypt /etc/nginx/` подскажет тебе где в конфигах прописаны сертификаты.

Comment: grep: /etc/nginx/: Is a directory. там я и нашел файл nginx.conf, в котором из SSL настроек вижу только: ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100186/discussion-between-andrey-mihalev-and-amsterdam).